# What bound does Chebychev’s inequality give for $P(Y ≥ 3 \text{ or } Y ≤ 1)$?

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-distribution, integral-inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose you flip four fair coins. Let Y be the number of heads obtained.
(a) What bound does Chebychev’s inequality give for $P(Y ≥ 3 \text{ or } Y ≤ 1)$?

---

$E(Y) = \sum_{y=1}^{4}yP(Y = y) = \sum_{y=1}^{4}y \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(1+2+3+4) = 5 \neq 2$

$E(Y^2) = \sum_{y=1}^{4}y^2P(Y = y) = \frac{1}{2}(1^2 +2^2 + 3^2+4^2) = 15$

$Var(Y) = 15 - 25 = -10 \neq 1$

(a) $P(Y ≥ 3 \text{ or } Y ≤ 1) = P(|Y -E(X)| \geq ?)$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you mean [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)?  What about Markov's inequality [many sources, especially in analysis, refer to it as Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)? I was thinking $P(|Y-2|\ge 1) \le E[|Y-2|]$

Comment: Isn't Chebyshev's just an extended Markov's inequality for all numbers? But yeah, the question says chebyshev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bas bas, $P(Y=y) \ne \frac 1 2$...$Y$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n=4, p = \frac 1 2$ soooo $$P(Y=y) = \binom{4}{y}(\frac12)^{4} $$ In [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),

$$E[Y] = np = 2, Var[Y] = np(1-p)=1$$

By Chebyshev's,

$$P(|Y-2| \ge k(1)=k) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

You have the right idea choosing $k=1$.

$$\therefore, P(|Y-2| \ge 1) \le 1$$